# Wordpress upload file size error even after raising php limits

Tags: php, posts, uploads, php.ini

I get 'The uploaded file exceeds the uploadmaxfilesize directive in php.ini.' error while trying to upload a plugin which is just 5.1MB. I have raised the limits in php.ini file and also thru webmin.

This is my php.ini file

```
max_input_time = 24000
max_execution_time = 24000
upload_max_filesize = 12000M
post_max_size = 24000M
memory_limit = 12000M
```

Here is my nginx.conf file. I have also increased clientmaxbody_size under server and http.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
client_max_body_size 24000M;
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
              '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
              '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

 access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
 .........
 server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
 server {
 client_max_body_size 24000M;
 server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
 .....
```

Comment: if that is what the error says, then you must be making changes in the wrong place. At the very least you should find or write a utility that will let you debug that problm outside of wordpress (like a small php file handling upload in the old fashioned way)

Comment: also check that it isn't being throttled in `wp-config.php` & restart the server after changing php config.

Comment: I tried uploading info.php and I was indeed editing the correct file. wp-config.php isn't being throttled.

Comment: `phpinfo()` will show you which config file is being used so you can edit the correct one.  In my local environment, it is the fifth row of the info table output.

Comment: I used the same command. I did edit the right php.ini

Comment: ... so again people just ignore my comments :( The most important skill you should have is to be able to debug things yourself. You have a problem that might be wordpress code related or server configuration related. Until you will get one of them out of the equation you will not know where to continue to look for the issue. As you are the only one that has access to your server, no one else will be able to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** You MUST reboot your server or reload your web server (Apache or Nginx) to ensure the changes take effect after each step.

You can first try to add the following to your theme's functions.php file. If it does not work, then remove it. If it does, I recommend you create a child theme so the code will remain active even after file changes during theme updates.

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

Second, you can try adding a php.ini file with the following contents to the root of the directory where your wordpress installation is. It is possible that Wordpress is not reading from the php.ini file located at the php directory.

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

The final thing you could try, if you want to change to apache web server rather than nginx is add the following to your .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

**EDIT:**
You can attempt to add this to your wp-config.php file at the end:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Now do step one once more. Then clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: I am with twenty seventeen theme, Should I try this? I have tried the second method but it didn't work. I have no intention to switch to apache.

Comment: Yes, the worst that could happen is it does not work. I read your post on Digital Ocean forums and wanted to ask if you rebooted your server after changing the php limits? Also, what php version are you on?

Comment: Nope I haven't rebooted my server. Php version is 7. The biggest problem is that I am not able to restore my website backup, the process fails due to memory limitations

Comment: You have to reboot for the changes to take effect. Nginx loads all of this stuff at startup, therefore you must either reload Nginx or restart the whole server. This is most likely what your problem is.

Comment: I reloaded nginx but I have rebooted my system.

Comment: Update us on the status of your issue.

Comment: Thank You! But none of this worked. I ended up switching to Ubuntu with no control panel